# Prove that if $ x_n = \sum_{k = 2}^n\sum_{m = 2}^k (m\ln{m})^{-1}$ then $ \lim(x_n)=\infty.$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $$\lim x_n=\infty$$

> **Hint:** Show that $x_{2^k} \geq (2\ln2)^{-1}(1 + 2^{-1} +\ldots + k^{-1})$

I am absolutely confused at how to approach this question. If I could just receive a tip it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By the way this is for Real Analysis, so need to prove it rigorously

Comment: No the title is edited wrong. the terms are x_n=1/(2ln2)+1/(3ln3)+...+1/(nln(n)).

Comment: That title is too long for the front page. Reducing it to a sum is neater.

Comment: No, but if you switch it into an infinite sum the question is VERY different. I am looking for the sum of all the TERMS, each term being what is specified in the title.

Comment: It's not infinite if it ends at $n$. Or did someone else set it to infinity? Also, I'm confused, because your question asks if it does approach infinity.

Comment: no but the series would be 1/(2ln2)+1/(3ln3)+1/(4ln4)....

Comment: What I'm looking for is 1/(2ln2)+(1/(2ln2)+1/(3ln3))+(1/(2ln2)+1/(3ln3)+1/(4ln4))+...

Comment: @FelicioGrande Your formatting does not indicate that. I will edit it to write what you intended.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how to use LaTeX so I can't express myself the way I want to.

Comment: Is this more accurate? Prove that if $ x_n = \sum_{k = 2}^n\sum_{m = 2}^k (m\ln{m})^{-1}$ then $ \lim(x_n)=\infty.$

Comment: yes, this is what I am trying to express.

Comment: Hint: use the P-series test. Are you using rudin?

Answer (score 0):

For all $k\ge2$
$$
\sum_{m=2}^k\frac{1}{m\,\ln m}\ge\frac{1}{2\ln 2}.
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{m=2}^k\frac{1}{m\,\ln m}\ge(n-1)\frac{1}{2\ln 2}.
$$
Am I missing something?

Even more,
$$
\sum_{m=2}^k\frac{1}{m\,\ln m}\ge\int_2^{m+1}\frac{dx}{x\,\ln x}=\ln(\ln(m+1))-\ln(\ln2).
$$

Comment: I am not allowed to use calculus of any kind. I need to prove it rigorously.

Comment: You mean calculus is not rigorous? Any way, the first method is elementary and does not use calculus.